# Can one draw a cube using different method/drawing mode?

Tags: 3d, java, android, opengl-es, cubemap

I've just started learning gamedev (in particular android EGL based) and have ran over a code from Pro Android Games 2 that looks as follows:

> /*  * Copyright (C) 2007 Google Inc. 
>   *  * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); 
>   * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.  * You
>   may obtain a copy of the License at  *
>   *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
>   *  * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software  *
>   distributed under the License is
>   distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,  *
>   WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF
>   ANY KIND, either express or implied. 
>   * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and  *
>   limitations under the License.  */
>
> package opengl.scenes.cubes;
>
> import java.nio.ByteBuffer; import
>   java.nio.ByteOrder; import
>   java.nio.IntBuffer;
>
> import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;
>
> public class Cube {
>
> ```
> public Cube(){
>
>     int one = 0x10000;
>     int vertices[] = {
>             -one, -one, -one,
>             one, -one, -one,
>             one,  one, -one,
>             -one,  one, -one,
>             -one, -one,  one,
>             one, -one,  one,
>             one,  one,  one,
>             -one,  one,  one,
>     };
>
>     int colors[] = {
>             0,    0,    0,  one,
>             one,    0,    0,  one,
>             one,  one,    0,  one,
>             0,  one,    0,  one,
>             0,    0,  one,  one,
>             one,    0,  one,  one,
>             one,  one,  one,  one,
>             0,  one,  one,  one,
>     };
>
>     byte indices[] = {
>             0, 4, 5,    0, 5, 1,
>             1, 5, 6,    1, 6, 2,
>             2, 6, 7,    2, 7, 3,
>             3, 7, 4,    3, 4, 0,
>             4, 7, 6,    4, 6, 5,
>             3, 0, 1,    3, 1, 2
>     };
>
>     // Buffers to be passed to gl*Pointer() functions
>     // must be direct, i.e., they must be placed on the
>     // native heap where the garbage collector cannot vbb.asIntBuffer()
>     // move them.
>     //
>     // Buffers with multi-byte datatypes (e.g., short, int, float)
>     // must have their byte order set to native order
>
>     ByteBuffer vbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length*4);
>     vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
>     mVertexBuffer = vbb.asIntBuffer();
>     mVertexBuffer.put(vertices);
>     mVertexBuffer.position(0);
>
>     ByteBuffer cbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(colors.length*4);
>     cbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
>     mColorBuffer = cbb.asIntBuffer();
>     mColorBuffer.put(colors);
>     mColorBuffer.position(0);
>
>     mIndexBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(indices.length);
>     mIndexBuffer.put(indices);
>     mIndexBuffer.position(0);
> }
>
> public void draw(GL10 gl)
> {
>     gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CW);
>     gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FIXED, 0, mVertexBuffer);
>     gl.glColorPointer(4, GL10.GL_FIXED, 0, mColorBuffer);
>     gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, 36, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, mIndexBuffer);
> }
>
> private IntBuffer   mVertexBuffer;
> private IntBuffer   mColorBuffer;
> private ByteBuffer  mIndexBuffer;}
> ```

So it suggests to draw a cube using triangles. My question is: can I draw the same cube using GL_TPOLYGON? If so, isn't that an easier/more understandable way to do things?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is indeed possible to draw polygons using OpenGL by passing GL_POLYGON instead of GL_TRIANGLES as the first parameter of glDrawElements(). Unfortunately, this is not supported in OpenGL ES, which is the subset of OpenGL that's available for your platform.

In addition to GL_POLYGON, the GL_QUADS and GL_QUAD_STRIP primitives are not supported either.

Fortunately, there's nothing you can do with quads that you can't do with triangles.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in this thread: [Why do game engines convert models to triangles compared to keeping it as four side polygon](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/9511/why-do-game-engines-convert-models-to-triangles-compared-to-keeping-it-as-four-si/9532#9532) triangles are what we generally use.

If you want to work in quads, add some higher level code to add quads to an index buffer that then adds two triangles.